Automating manipulation of a GUI-based app on a Windows server with Java over RDP from Linux
I apologize for the dense title and question, but I've read through just about every existing thread that's remotely relevant and haven't found a solution to my specific problem.
My goal is to automate the initialization of a GUI-based app that runs on a Windows server and requires various buttons to be clicked, but I have a number of constraints that make this particularly challenging (and so far, comically complicated).

The system that starts the app has to be triggered by a shell script on a Linux machine--this is extremely constraining but unfortunately mandatory by nature of our system.
The only way I've found to automate the startup of the Win server app is to use a PyAutoGui script. This works when run on the server, but I need a way to start the script from outside the server in an automated way.
PyAutoGUI needs a visual desktop environment to work, so just calling the python script with SSH won't work AFAIK.

So far, I've managed to put together a Rube-Goldberg machine of different tools that gets me as far as automating opening an RDP window into the Windows server from the Linux machine as follows:
Original Linux program that knows when the GUI app needs to run triggers a shell script that curls an HTTP call to a Java service listening on the Linux system -- The Java service then execs a gnome terminal that runs rdesktop to open a remote connection to the Windows server.
From here though, I don't know any elegant ways (none of this is elegant so far, I know) to invoke the python script on the Win server to actually start the app. My only idea is to use ANOTHER PyAutoGUI script run from the Linux machine to automate selecting and running the other script through the RDP window. This seems like a bridge too far at this point, so any alternative approaches (ideally using Java) to do what I want on the Windows server I've opened an RDP connection to would be much appreciated.
I again apologize for the incredibly disjointed problem and any better solutions/suggestions at any point are welcome.

Some preemptive clarification: The target Windows app has no API or anything, starting it by clicking buttons (or at least entering keystrokes) is the only way.

It looks like your question is "help me set up this custom incredibly convoluted and complex Rube Goldberg contraption". The solution is likely not to do any of this, to re-think the entire problem and solutions. What is your ultimate goal? I'm not talking about starting up the GUI remotely but rather what does the GUI do? What is its purpose?

Create a virtual machine with the complicated gui running and fully setup. Take a snapshot. Use an orchestration service to restore the snapshot to the good state as needed.

@HovercraftFullOfEels The GUI app is a data recorder for a physical system that's provided to us by a 3rd party vendor (both the physical system and the app). The ultimate goal is to make sure this app is started reliably and automatically. Right now, the primary remaining hurdle that I'm requesting help on is getting from a Java-actuated RDP window to the Python script on the remote-connected machine. I was naively hoping I would get a "oh, you just need to use this Java library that's perfect for the task!" but no such luck. If there's no good solution, I'm prepared to go with the "bad" one.
